# Tax implications for buying property in another country

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, property-taxes

1. Are there are tax implications for buying an apartment in another country (as a US resident with Green Card)? Does the IRS require to pay taxes in the country in which you live or do you pay property taxes to the country in which the apartment is?
2. I am looking for resources about this and I don't know who should I contact. A lawyer? A real estate agent?
3. Do you know if I can get a normal mortgage from a US bank for a property that not in the US?

Answer (score 7):

> Are there are tax implications for buying an apartment in another
>   country (as a US resident with Green Card)?

Yes. You have to report your foreign bank accounts if your balances are above certain level (search for FBAR requirements and form 8938).

If you hold the property through an entity (trust, LLC, partnership, corporation, etc) - there are more reporting requirements.

> Does the IRS require to pay taxes in the country in which you live or
>   do you pay property taxes to the country in which the apartment is?

The IRS doesn't require anything, the laws require. US laws require you to pay taxes in the US. Foreign country's laws may require you to pay taxes there. These are unrelated requirements, unless there's a tax treaty between that country and the US that says something else. You may be able to credit some of the taxes paid in the foreign country against your US tax liabilities. See form 1116.

> I am looking for resources about this and I don't know who should I
>   contact. A lawyer? A real estate agent?

About taxes? Real estate agent? Why? Do you ask your travel agent what pills you'd need if you get a flu when you travel?

You need a **tax adviser**. People who are legally allowed to give tax advice in the US must be licensed as either EA (IRS issued certification), CPA or Attorney (both issued by States, so you need to talk to the one licensed by your state).

You would probably look for a EA/CPA licensed in your state, this is not something that requires an attorney. Look for someone who is proficient in international taxation, and has experience working with your specific target country, or a lot of international experience in general.

> Do you know if I can get a normal mortgage from a US bank for a
>   property that not in the US?

Highly unlikely. You might be able to get something from private lenders willing to take a risk, but it wouldn't be a "normal" (FHA/Fannie May/Freddie Mac backed) mortgage, so the rates would be much higher.